# How do I configure 'ConsumerGroup` in local.settings.json while developing Azure Function Version 2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have below code to catch all the messages arrives at `IoT Hub`

```
    [FunctionName("device-message--funcapp-v2")]
    public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("testhub", 
                       Connection = "IoTHubEventEndPoint", 
                       ConsumerGroup = "ActualConsumerGroup")]EventData message, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger:
       {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");     
    }
```

This works fine as expected, but now I do not want to hard code the `ConsumerGroup`. So I added below configuraiton entry in `local.settings.json`

```
   {
     "IsEncrypted": false,
     "Values": {
          "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
          "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
          "EventHub": "",
          "CosmosDb": "",
         "ConfigurationConsumerGroup": "ActualConsumerGroup"
          }
        }
```

and changed code as below

```
       [FunctionName("device-message--funcapp-v2")]
    public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("testhub", 
        Connection = "IoTHubEventEndPoint", 
        ConsumerGroup = "ConfigurationConsumerGroup")]EventData message, 
        ILogger log)
```

But it fails.

> [1/18/2019 9:47:11 AM] Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs: The messaging entity 'iothub-ns-testhub-945897-3a6f492cc4:eventhub:lctesthub~8191|ConfigurationConsumerGroup' could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ConsumerGroup = "%ConfigurationConsumerGroup%"` to read settings from local.settings.json. Check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings). Note that the connection property of triggers and bindings is a special case and automatically resolves values as app settings, without percent signs.